# Getting a empty entry for query in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So I want to be able to get information from MySQL. In my PHP code, I call the query and echo the info in this sort of fashion:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `person`";
$rs = $COMMON->executeQuery($sql, $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]);

while($row = mysql_fetch_row($rs)){
    echo ("Name: ".$row['name']."<br />";
    echo ("Gender: ".$row['gender']."<br />";
    echo ("Age: ".$row['age']."<br />";
};
```

Though, the actual value of `$row['name']` and the rest is completely blank. Not even a single space. Though, when I call it by the actual column index like so `$row[1]`, it gives me the right value.

So, for example, lets say this had three person in the table. The end result page would look like this:

```
Name: 
Gender: 
Age: 
Name: 
Gender: 
Age:
Name: 
Gender: 
Age:
```

Is something I'm doing wrong? Why is it giving me this empty string instead of the query value?

MySQL database is saved on MyPHPAdmin. I don't know if it makes a difference or not. If there is anymore information missing that you deem necessary, please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to be using [`mysql_fetch_assoc()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) instead of `mysql_fetch_row()`. `mysql_fetch_assoc()` returns an associative array of your results. `mysql_fetch_row()` returns a numerical array.

[Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: This really doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Yes it does. The very first line is the solution.

Comment: And then some good info afterwards. He doesn't have 47300+ rep. arbitrarily

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to:-

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `person`";
$rs = $COMMON->executeQuery($sql, $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)){
echo ("Name: ".$row['name']."<br />";
echo ("Gender: ".$row['gender']."<br />";
echo ("Age: ".$row['age']."<br />";
};
```

mysql_fetch_assoc(), as the name implies it will return an associative array (with the column names as keys and the values as the row values).